# Exiting a bool void function when the input is negative c++

Tags: c++

I have this one problem with this program.
In the bool void function it is supposed to return true if the exponent value is negative
which should exit the main functions loop.  I'm unable to come up with a way to exit this loop though
because it keeps looping because the value is true.

```
//Input: The input will consist of a data file that contains a series
//of x values and polynomials. Each term will consist of a coefficient
//and an exponent. The polynomial will be terminated by a negative exponent.
//Output: For each polynomial display the x value as well as a nicely
//formatted polynomial along with the value of the polynomial at x.
//Example: When x = 2
//         2x^2 - x + 3 = 9

#include iostream
#include cmath
#include iomanip
#include cstdlib
using namespace std;

void get_term(int &, int &);
bool end_poly(int);
void print_term(int, int, int &);
double evaluate_term(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int xvalue;           //value for x used in evaluation of polynomial
    int coef, exponent;   //coefficient and exponent of current polynomial term
    double result;        //value of polynomial
    int term_count;       //counts # of terms displayed

    cout << fixed << setprecision(0); //suppress decimal when doubles displayed
    cin >> xvalue;                    //get first x value

    while (cin)
    {
        term_count = 0;               //no terms have been displayed yet
        result = 0;                   //initialize accumulator for polynomial
        cout << "When x = " << xvalue << endl;
        get_term(coef, exponent);     //get coefficient and exponent of 1st term
        while (!end_poly(exponent))
        {
            result = result + evaluate_term(coef, exponent, xvalue);
            print_term(coef, exponent, term_count);
            get_term(coef, exponent);
        }
        cout << " = " << result << endl << endl;
        cin >> xvalue;
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_term(int &coefficient, int &exponent)
//get_term is passed 2 int parameters that represent the coefficient and exponent
//of a term. The function reads to 2  values and passes them back to the calling
//function.
{
    cin >> coefficient >> exponent;
    return;
}

bool end_poly(int exponent)
{
    while (exponent < 0)
        true;
}

void print_term(int coef, int exp, int &term_count)
{
    int tempcoef = 0; // holds the absolute value of coef
    if (term_count != 0 && coef < -1 && exp > 1)
    {
        tempcoef = abs(coef);
        cout << " - " << tempcoef << "x^" << exp;
    }
    if (term_count != 0 && coef == -1 && exp > 1)
        cout << " - x^" << exp;
    if (term_count == 0 && coef > 1 && exp > 1)
        cout << coef << "x^" << exp;
    if (term_count != 0 && coef > 1 && exp > 1)
        cout << " + " << coef << "x^" << exp;
    if (term_count > 0 && coef == 1 && exp > 1)
        cout << " + x^" << exp;
    if (term_count == 0 && coef == 1 && exp > 1)
        cout << "x^" << exp;
    if (term_count != 0 && coef < -1 && exp == 1)
    {
        tempcoef = abs(coef);
        cout << " - " << tempcoef << "x";
    }
    if (term_count != 0 && coef == -1 && exp == 1)
        cout << " - x";
    if (term_count == 0 && coef > 1 && exp == 1)
        cout << coef << "x";
    if (term_count != 0 && coef > 1 && exp == 1)
        cout << " + " << coef << "x";
    if (term_count > 0 && coef == 1 && exp == 1)
        cout << " + x";
    if (term_count == 0 && coef == 1 && exp == 1)
        cout << "x";
    if (term_count == 0 && coef < -1 && exp == 0)
    {
        tempcoef = abs(coef);
        cout << "-" << tempcoef;
    }
    if (term_count == 0 && coef == -1 && exp == 0)
        cout << "-1";
    if (term_count != 0 && coef < -1 && exp == 0)
    {
        tempcoef = abs(coef);
        cout << " - " << tempcoef;
    }
    if (term_count != 0 && coef == -1 && exp == 0)
        cout << " - 1";
    if (term_count == 0 && coef > 1 && exp == 0)
        cout << coef;
    if (term_count != 0 && coef > 1 && exp == 0)
        cout << " + " << coef;
    if (term_count > 0 && coef == 1 && exp == 0)
        cout << " + 1";
    if (term_count == 0 && coef == 1 && exp == 0)
        cout << "1";
    term_count = term_count + 1;
}

double evaluate_term(int coef, int exponent, int x)
{
    coef *pow(x , exponent);
}
```

Comment: What is a "bool void function", and where is it?

Comment: What is `while (exponent < 0) true;` supposed to be doing? C++ is not Pascal. You need a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the function *is supposed to return true if the exponent value is negative*, it should look like this:

```
bool end_poly(int exponent)
{
    return exponent < 0;
}
```

Comment: so I did that and the output for print_term is correct, but now the math has messed up and returned the wrong answers why would that be?

Comment: @Trevor this is a different question